# Django update functionality

Tags: django

I've got a model, with two forms. When a calf is scanned in, it gets one set of information, then when it's shipped out, it's a separate form with different information. For example when scanned in, it takes DOB and arrival date, when scanned out we need ship out date, milk consumed during it's stay(2 quarts per day), where it is going, and any medication while at the depot.

Right now I have the two forms below:

[Scan in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOxaM.png)

[scan out form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZB6b.png)

Now you can see when I try to update an entry I get an error that it already exists

Here is my view:

---

```
def scanoutcalf(request, id=None):
form = ScanOutForm(request.POST or None)

context = {
    'form': form,
}

form = ScanOutForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()

return render(request, 'calves/scan_out.html', context)
```

---

And my forms:

```
class ScanOutForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Calf
    fields = [
        'eid', 'ship_out_date', 'program', 'destination', 'medical_history', 'milk_consumed'
    ]
    widgets = {
        'ship_out_date': forms.widgets.DateInput(
            attrs={'type': 'date'}
        )
    }
```

I've googled around, but couldn't find an example of how to update without having to create a queryset or a URL with instance ID.

The idea here is that a user can just scan when calves are leaving, update with the information that is essential, and the form will check the EID, and update the DB if it exists, or create it if it doesn't. Any help would amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the instance before saving and pass into `ScanOutForm` as keyword argument `instance`.

Like so:

```py
def scanoutcalf(request, id=None):
    form = ScanOutForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            calf = Calf.objects.get(eid=request.POST['eid'])
        except:
            calf = None
        if calf is not None:
            form = ScanOutForm(request.POST, instance=calf)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

    return render(request, 'calves/scan_out.html', context)
```

> *Note: As you use unique identifier in the form this must be directly extracted from `request.POST` with validation.*

Comment: Thank you so much! That does exactly what I want. I can see the row in the DB has updated. But I'm still seeing the error, that the calf EID already exists. This may be a dumb follow up, but I'd like to see the form just return blank and maybe an "Entry updated" upon success

Comment: If you could edit your question with the full error traceback that would be helpful so I can have a look where the error originates. In terms of post form success, just add a redirect of your choice after the `form.save()` line. Help on this can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect